# puedo logearme desde android studio y mysql por token

Tags: mysql, android-studio, android-volley

**quiero loguearme con un usuario existe desde una api,
y si hago la prueba desde postman me sale el status 200,y si lo hago desde android con el email y password existente me me deja pasar al la actividad principal.
y si pongo una contraseña incorrecta o un email incorrecto debería salirme el error 401 y decirme error, pero aun asi me deja pasar a la pantalla principal**

**ME SALE EL SIGUIENTE MENSAJE
D/Volley: [484] BasicNetwork.logSlowRequests: HTTP response for request=<[ ] http://actasentrega.cispcolombia.org/api/login 0xcc35f14f NORMAL 1> [lifetime=8567], [size=98], [rc=200], [retryCount=1]
W/ActivityThread: handleWindowVisibility: no activity for token android.os.BinderProxy@bca6c25
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xec385300: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xec383700)
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xec385300: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xec383700)**

```
 _btnlogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                validarUsuario("http://actasentrega.colombia.org/api/login");
}
        });


    }
```

```
 private void validarUsuario(String URL){
        StringRequest stringRequest =new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                //VALIDAMOS QUE EL RESPONSE NO ESTE VACIIO
                if (!response.isEmpty()) {

                    Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }else {
                    Toast.makeText(Inicio.this, "EMAIL O CONTRASEÑA INCORRECTOS", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(Inicio.this, error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        }){
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String,String> parametros=new HashMap<String, String>();
                parametros.put("email",_txtCorreo.getText().toString());
                parametros.put("password",_txtContrase.getText().toString());

                return parametros;
            }
        };

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);

    }



    }
```

Comment: Hola Cristian, este sitio es en castellano, por favor, pulsa en [edit]  para traducir tu pregunta o bien plantéala en el sito en inglés.

Comment: Esto sólo no te sirve: `if (!response.isEmpty()) {` porque el hecho de que el login sea rechazado no implica necesariamente que `response` esté vacío o no. Cuando no se permite el login, debes mandar en `response` un identificador por ejemplo para indicar que el login fue rechazado, o bien leer el código de error que emitió el servidor. Creo que es más seguro lo primero.

Comment: gracias. te puedo pedir un ejemplo para la condicion  if :

Comment: @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                //VALIDAMOS QUE EL RESPONSE NO ESTE VACIIO
                if (!response.isEmpty() && (response == null)) {
                    Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }else {
                    Toast.makeText(Inicio.this, "EMAIL O CONTRASEÑA INCORRECTOS", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                **asi me sale con son incorrectos. aunque son correctos**

Comment: Dado que estás mandando un `StringRequest` en caso de que no se pueda loguear, basta con que hagas algo como `echo "error";` en el servidor. Y luego en `Volley` haces algo así: `if (!response.equals("error")) { /*Se pudo loguear*/ } else { /*No se pudo loguear*/ }` Aunque siempre trabajar con `StringRequest` es más precario, es mejor trabajar con JSON, porque así organizas mejor las cosas y pones claves específicas. Si lo dejas como String sería bueno que preguntes también si `response` no vino vacío, por si acaso.

Comment: Antes modificar en el servidor, verifica qué devuelve éste cuando no se puede loguear, quizá ya emite algún mensaje. Haz un `Log` de `response` para ver qué muestra.